# Replace all single quotes with two single quotes in a string

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to read value from DB using c#.
The query string contains multiple single quotes - such as: Esca'pes' (the query strings are being read from a text file)

So, I wanted to replace all the single quotes with two single quotes before forming the SQL query. My code is as below:

```
if (name.Contains('\''))
{
    name = name.Replace('\'','\''');  
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: How to fix what? Are you getting an error? I'll also add that if preventing SQL injection is your goal you'd be better off using parametrized queries.

Comment: `name.Replace("'","''")` is probably what you're after?

Comment: As others have mentioned, this is a big no-no in the DBMS world because someone could potentially pass a value in the "parameters" that ends up executing a query you didn't intend for them to be able to run, potentially compromising your system.  Search for "sql injection" on Google for more info on how this goes bad and look no further back than the most recent Sony playstation network hack for an example of how not following this advice can bite you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use strings, not char literals.

```
name = name.Replace("'", "''");
```

However it sounds like you're concatenating SQL strings together. This is a huge "**DO NOT**" rule in modern application design because of the risk of SQL injection. Please use SQL parameters instead. Every modern DBMS platform supports them, including ADO.NET with SQL Server and MySQL, even Access supports them.

Answer (score 3):

`name = name.Replace("'","''");`

On an unrelated note, you're concatenating strings for use in SQL?  Try parameters instead, that's what they're meant for.  You're probably making it harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to replace a single character with two characters, you need to use the String overload of Replace

```
if (name.Contains('\''))
{
    name = name.Replace("'","''");  
}
```

(Note: single quotes don't require escaping in Strings like they do in character notation.)

Comment: Why we need to check whether string contains single quote or not as replace will only change string if it contains that pattern

Comment: @Kapil was merely mirroring the original user's question, and only replaced the part that wasn't working.