# Replace a single quote ( ' ) with double quote ( ' ')

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop

I am trying to replace a single quote ( ' ) with a double quote ( ' ' ) and not with this character :  ( " )

Actually, I am trying this :

```
Text.Replace("'", "''");
Text.Replace("'", "\''");
Text.Replace("\'", "''");
Text.Reaplce("\'", "\''");
```

But none of this does works...
I am willing to do this and am really demanding it, so it would be great if you could help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace all single quotes with two single quotes in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277517/replace-all-single-quotes-with-two-single-quotes-in-a-string)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277517/replace-all-single-quotes-with-two-single-quotes-in-a-string

Comment: Your first code line should work. Make sure you are catching the output by storing it in some variable. like `var res = Text.Replace("'", "''");`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `Replace("'", "''");`. However keep in mind that the `Replace` method returns a new string. So it has to be:

`Text = Text.Replace("'", "''");`